# Linking to hosted fonts using css from a different server

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am having a problem getting some fonts that I am hosting on one server to display on my Duda site. When I use the trial version it works fine with their code, but now since I have to host the fonts myself, and I cannot do so on Duda servers, it is not working.

I have this in the site.css (global) file:

```
* {
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: 'AvenirLTPro-Light';
}
```

I have this in the head-section.html:

```
<link href="http://www.XXXXXXX.com/fonts/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

I have this css file hosted at www.XXXXXXX.com:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirLTPro-Light';src: url('http://XXXXXX/fonts/webfonts/3247CE_1_0.eot');
```

Which is the contents of the css file linked to above. The XXX's are a valid domain and I can link to these fonts from another site. All the font files are in the fonts/webfonts folder and can be reached.

I am not sure why it wont show on the Duda site now. There must be a problem with my css? Or would the order that the files are being read have anything to do with it? Any help appreciated.

Sorry I also should have said I have links to other font types, it just wouldnt let me post that many links in there, so I also have ttf, woff, woff2.

Comment: Start by looking into your browsers development console and 1. examine the outgoing requests to those font files and 2. the application of fonts.

Comment: Ok so I can see this: Blocked loading mixed active content "http://www.XXXXXX.com/fonts/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css"[Learn More]499c3e70  I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Ah ok so it seems this is an insecure link. The font shows fine when I disable protection on the browser, however this isnt a fix. I now get the following:  This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.[Learn More]widgets.twimg.com
Loading mixed (insecure) active content "http://www.XXXXX.xom/fonts/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css" on a secure page[Learn More]home
GET 
http://www.XXXXXXX.xom/fonts/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css

Comment: What would the best solution be?

Comment: Ah, so you load your page with https and then try to load the font via http. That indeed is a security issue which is why browsers block that by default. The obvious solution is to 1. use a valid ssl certificate for that server offering the font files, reference them via https and 2. to whitelist that system in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: Excellent thank you

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you made the font on .woff because the one you used does not support all browsers while .woff is on all browsers. There isn't anything wrong with your code that I noticed. See the link for more information and clarification:
[w3schools.com: CSS3 Web Fonts](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)

Comment: Sorry I also should have said I have links to other font types, it just wouldnt let me post that many links in there, so I also have ttf, woff, woff2.